# How to remove the vertical space of TopAppBar in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose-material3

How to remove the vertical space of [TopAppBar](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/app-bars) in Jetpack Compose?

[image]